# How android application and web application working?

Tags: android

I'm a little confused because I couldn't understand how android application working at the same time with web application . for example I have a web site and I wanna have a android app for my website and how can i programming at the same time , can i build my android app with php ?? this is the main question i have and i don't understand what i should do and how web site and android app working . for example Amazon has a android and ios app at the same and Amazon has a website , how those thing working together ???

Answer (score 0):

You can build a webview app that is app where you can display HTML with Css and maybe also JS. 
That is what google said about webview app:

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a WebView.

You can find more information about a webview app is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

If you have any other questions about it feel free to ask.